# $T(n) = 3T(n/3) + c$ using substitution, geometric series

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, geometric-series

so I have to find the asymptotic complexity of

$T(n) = 3Tn(n/3) + c$

using either the substitution method, a recursion tree or induction. I used the Master Theorem to find an answer, but can't use it to justify.

So I got n.

I decided to use substitution because we had not learned the other 2 methods yet. I got as far as finding

$k = \log_3 n$

and

$T(n) = 3^kT(n/3^k) + 3^{k-1} c + 3^{k-2} c + 3^{k-3} c + 3^{k-k} c$

and when substituted k in:

$T(n) = 3^{\log_3n}T(n/3^{\log_3n}) + 3^{{\log_3n}-1} c + 3^{{\log_3n}-2} c + 3^{{\log_3n}-3} c + 3^{k-k} c$

$T(n) = nT(1) + 3^{{\log_3n}-1} c + 3^{{\log_3n}-2} c + 3^{{\log_3n}-3} c + 3^{{\log_3n}-{\log_3n}} c$

But I'm stuck here with the geometric series and how to get the exponents to be correct...or what they are

would it be: $n/3^n$ ? The $-1, -2, -3$ , of the equation are confusing me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify the geometric series, your series is (when written backwards):

$$T(n) = nT(1)+c\sum_{k=1}^{\log_3(n)}3^k.$$

Now use the fact that the above series is of order $3^{\log_3(n)}=n$. So $T(n)=O(n)$.

Comment: so when you continue with the summation would it be $T(n) = nT(1) + cn(log_3n -1)$ and why is it BigO(n) not Theta(n)

Answer (score 0):

Your are close;
you just have to sum the geometric series.

You have

$\begin{array}\\
T(n)
=nT(1)+c\sum_{k =1}^{\log_3n}3^{\log_3 n - k}\\
=nT(1)+c\sum_{k =1}^{\log_3n}3^{\log_3 n}3^{ - k}\\
=nT(1)+c3^{\log_3 n}\sum_{k =1}^{\log_3n}3^{ - k}\\
=nT(1)+cn\sum_{k =1}^{\log_3n}3^{ - k}\\
\end{array}
$

Now use
$\sum_{k=1}^m x^k
=x\frac{x^{m}-1}{x-1}
$
or
its equivalent
$\sum_{k=1}^m x^{-k}
=x^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x^{-k}
=x^{-1}\frac{1-x^{-m}}{1-x^{-1}}
$.

We get for the sum,
with $x = 3$
and
$m = \log_3 n$,
$\sum_{k =1}^{\log_3n}3^{ - k}
=\frac13\frac{1-3^{-\log_3 n}}{1-\frac13}
=\frac{1-\frac1{n}}{2}
$.

Combine these and you are done.

You really need to be able to sum
a geometric progression,
in all its various disguises.
This is a basic tool
in math and computer science,
and if you have trouble doing this,
please get help.

Comment: when you use the lower bound as k....shouldn't it be another variable to avoid confusion?

Comment: I use $k$ only as the index of summation, so I think it's ok.